# Time Machine Back Up of external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, partition

I have two partitions on my hard drive. One of them is used for the time machine back up. On the other one I've got files that I would like to back up with Time Machine too.

Unfortunately I can't select this partition under Time-Machine-Settings "Exclude".

The little amount of free space on the Back Up partition shouldn't be the cause for this right?

Does anyone know what to do? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add the output from `diskutil list` when your external backup disk is connected to your question. Then we can see the layout and advise accordingly. In the meantime see my answer below, which may change depending on the output you can update us with. Also please add a screenshot of the exclusion list when the external disk is connected. See the page help on how to add the correct formatting to the OP with backticks and the image tags.

Answer (score 1):

Any external non-TM filesystems are added to the exclusion list by default when a disk is connected, as by default TM **wouldn't** backup externals. You would normally *remove* this filesystem from the exclusion list to allow backups.

Additional filesystems on the internal disk do not appear in the exclusion list by default, and so **would** be included in the backup if no further customisation were performed.

Bear in mind though that a backup to the same physical device is not really suitable as a backup. If you lose the disk (through either physical loss or corruption), you lose both the backup and the originals. Instead if you keep originals and backup separate you have better odds when you (inevitably!) lose a device.