# How can I get Time Machine to back up the Photos library that lives on my external drive?

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk

(*I see that this has somewhat been brought up in [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248136/can-time-machine-back-up-an-external-hard-drive-in-addition-to-internal-one?rq=1) [unresolved](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457083/time-machine-back-up-of-external-hard-drive) questions, but I've gathered information that I think justifies it as a new question.*)

As with a lot of people, my on-board Mac SSD storage is insufficient for my Photos library and thus I've semi-permanently attached an external USB drive to the Mac which hosts a volume for the photos library amongst other things (APFS, FWIW). So naturally, I would like that external drive to be part of the Time Machine backup that is regularly maintained by the macOS (currently Monterey).

However, I noticed the other day that Time Machine is actually NOT making the external USB drive (or another WD Book for that matter) as part of the backup which lives on a NAS. I went into the Time Machine settings and checked that there are no exclusions for the USB drive and if I even attempt to hit the '+' to see if the drive or any of its top level folders are grayed out, I find that they're fine and I can actually exclude them (at which point those folders appear in the exclusion list).

I tested that the USB drive (and photos library) is still being excluded by using

```
tmutil isexcluded /Volumes/Photodrive/Photos\ Library.photolibrary
```

and it reports back as `[Excluded]`. I even explicitly did the `tmutil` command to remove the exclusion, which succeeds but *still* will report as `[Excluded]` by the "isexcluded" command.

Digging deeper, I extracted the system prefs with

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist
```

and removed all volume UUIDs from the `ExcludedVolumeUUIDs` section, made sure that the photos drive wasn't in any exclusion section, and actually made sure that the Volume UUID for that drive was in the `IncludedVolumeUUIDs` section. Re-wrote the plist in the system, rebooted, and then check again with the `tmutil` command and *STILL* the photos library is `[Excluded]`. To go one step further, I even checked that there are no hidden files such as `.com.apple.timemachine.nopresent` or whatever the name is on the drive; we're clean. I don't think there are any other locations where Time Machine keeps in/exclusion information.

So as far as I can tell, there is no reason why Time Machine won't back up the drive let alone present it in the "Exclude these items from backup" dialog that appears in the Time Machine options screen. I do understand that the default behavior of Time Machine is to NOT backup USB drives (only internally mounted ones), but especially with their now non-replaceable SSD designs, they **MUST** support the ability to recognize externally attached storage as a semi-permanent extension......no?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restoring a deleted or changed file or directory to your Photodrive volume using Time Machine? I have an external disk which is not in the `Exclude from Backups` list under Systems Settings->General->Time Machine->Options (Ventura) but for which `tmutil isexcluded` returns `[Excluded]` and yet, I can view now deleted directories or files using Time Machine and restore them. I wish it did not but I wonder if `tmutil isexcluded` is working properly.

Comment: @Alper - this is on Monterey.